# Ambiguous column name 'Year'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column `Year` and I need to write a stored procedure to get all of the records that fall within the current year.

When I write my stored procedure, I get the error mentioned in the title.

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: Please post your sql query, it sounds like you are joining tables which both have the same column name of "Year"

Comment: You are missing a lot of information here... show your stored procedure. What's the actual error. If you have multiple tables, alias or qualify the columns with the table names or alias'. That's most likely your issue.

Comment: You really should avoid using reserved words as object or column names. As already stated, without your code the best we can do is guess.

Comment: @dustytrash, I ought to flag your comment, but it made me smile so now I'm complicit.

Comment: @RyanWilson, I assumed Meta would have thoughts on your deleted comment, and it did. I've wondered myself how to handle this situation. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat

Comment: @EricBrandt What conclusion did you come to sir? I decided my comment was snarky, and I don't like to be snarky.

Comment: @RyanWilson, I find I agree with the accepted answer. Go ahead and summarize the comments in the form of an answer, but flag it as a Community Wiki post. The poster doesn't get (or, really, deserve) credit for upvotes on that, but the OP can accept the answer and let the question show up as, in fact, answered. Seems fair to all concerned to me.

Comment: @EricBrandt Yeah, I think that seems relatively fair, except the person who summed up the comments still gets a +15 for the accepted answer. Or does marking it as Community Wiki prevent those points as well?

Comment: @RyanWilson No points, no rep for a Community Wiki answer. Which I didn't know until just now, so your comment did some good (for me, anyway) because I hadn't looked into the Community Wiki thing at all previously.

Comment: @EricBrandt Thanks, I had not either. Thank you for the good information.

Comment: @user3643216 This will help... https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps.

Surround the column `year` with square brackets and reference it using the table name.

```
select mytable.[year]
from mytable
where mytable.[year] > 2007
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this means you have two tables and both have a year column and you are referencing one of them without saying what table it comes from. Make an alias for it. Also, you should provide more information on questions (and don't use reserved words as column names)